# Vue webpack template custom enviroment variables not works

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

I'm working on Vue SPA app with webpack template. How can I access enviroment variables from Vue? I'm doing this:

In config/dev.env.js

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  MY_VAR: '"aaaa"'
})
```

In main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = true

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  created () {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // development
    console.log(process.env.MY_VAR) // undefined
  }
})
```

But when I run project with npm run dev, my MY_VAR variable doesn't work? Why returns undefined? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is referencing to vrariable defined `dev.env.js` ?

Comment: No, I'm not. But a got the point. These enviroment properties are not accessible during runtime. So I switch to vue-config component.